# Eclipse SVN history view

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I wanted to look up the svn history of my project and Eclipse (Luna SR1 (4.4.1)) shows me somethin like that:

[image]

The last revision is the number 2479. This one I've edited a little bit.. What does the '*' and the bold text in "*2395" mean?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Isn't the bold one the one which you currently have checked out? Have you tried a `svn update`?

Answer (score 1):

That version indicates the current version in your workspace, the version that you use now

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But the only commits for this project were from my computer.. So if I make a commit with it (my pc), shouldn't it set the current version to the head revision automaticaly??!

Comment: It's a result of a switch/selection, manual selection, a mistake maybe. You can load first version.